# Lax SameSite and POST (2 minute)

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, csrf, session-management

I was going through this link https://medium.com/@renwa/bypass-samesite-cookies-default-to-lax-and-get-csrf-343ba09b9f2b to understand CSRF using samesite. Does that mean that the LAX+POST issue has been resolved by Chrome, which means that now there is [no 2-minute](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592) window by default that would prevent user from making a request?

The test I performed was I logged in using the code which created a cookie for me. Then after 3 minutes, I made a POST call to settings.php  that simply allowed me to update the cookie without any issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed me to update the cookie"? This isn't about updating cookies. The question is: Does the browser send a `SameSite=Lax` cookie in a cross-site POST request? If you claim Chrome does this even after 2 minutes, there's something wrong with your test.

Comment: The Chrome feature you're talking about is called `ShortLaxAllowUnsafeThreshold`. As far as I can tell from the source code, it's disabled by default and has to be enabled through the Chrome command line. By the way, this isn't an issue that needs to be resolved, it's a feature that the Chrome developers purposely implemented -- whether this feature is or good or bad idea is a different question.

Comment: @Ja1024 yes the browser sent the SameSite=Lax cookie even after two minutes in chrome. Also I think that the chrome was going to remove that update very soon and it is not even mentioned in their docs if they enabled it

Comment: @Ja1024 Also I cannot find any official documentation where it says that there is still 2 minute window, I think it's removed.

Comment: There's either a misunderstanding or a bug in your test, because this doesn't make sense. The whole purpose of `SameSite=Lax` is to prevent the browser from sending cookies in unsafe cross-site requests like POST. Chrome does have a feature to relax this restriction in the first 2 minutes after the cookie has been created. But after this time, the restriction *is* enforced even in Chrome, regardless of the feature. You're effectively claiming that Chrome doesn't honor `SameSite=Lax` at all, which I highly doubt. This would only be the case for ancient or customized versions of Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure you're making *cross-site* requests? What exactly are the test domains? (unless they're somehow confidential) How do other browsers like Firefox behave? If they also ignore `SameSite=Lax`, there's definitely an issue with your test setup.